# How to autofill table fields when a new item is created and update the existing one

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm working on a project in Laravel 8. I want users to be able to add a "service line" which contains the item's name, description, price and amount of hours. When a user adds an item, the rest of the fields will be automatically inserted based on the name of the item. This works fine on the first item that is going to be created, but if a user adds a new line by clicking the "add new item" button and select the item's name, the rest of the fields are not prefilled with description, price and hours. I think this has something to do with JS execution of functions and I need help to figure out how to solve this problem. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d79kG.png)

My HTML code:

```
            <div class="form-group row service" id="service-form">
        
                
            <div id="service-line">
                    
            </div>
            </div>

            <button type="button" id="new-item" class="btn">Add New Item</button>
```

Javascript:

```
        // Call function
     const services = <?php echo json_encode($services ); ?>
    displayItemsTable(services) 

    function displayItemsTable(services) {
        // Get the ID of service form
        const serviceform = document.querySelector('#service-form');
            // Output
                let output = `
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" id="table-services">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Hours</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" id="service" name="service" placeholder="select customer" value="Select service">
                                @foreach($services as $service)
                                        <option id="service" value="{{$service->id}}">{{$service->name}}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        
                        <td id="desc"></td>
                        <td id="price"></td>
                        <td id="hours"></td>

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                `;


            serviceform.innerHTML = output;

            addNewServiceLine(output, serviceform);
        }

    function addNewServiceLine(output, serviceform){
            document.querySelector('#new-item').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                serviceform.innerHTML += output;
            });
    }
    

    autoFillServiceData(services)

    function autoFillServiceData(services) {

        const options = document.querySelectorAll('#service');
        const tables = document.querySelectorAll('#table-services');

        for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) 
        {
            options[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
                console.log(options[i])

                    services.forEach( (service) => {
                
                        if(options[i].textContent == service.name)
                        {
                            document.querySelector("#desc").innerHTML = service.desc
                            document.querySelector('#price').innerHTML = service.price_per_hour
                            document.querySelector('#hours').innerHTML = service.hours
                        }
                    });
            });
        }

        
    }
```

Comment: I must admit, I don't have a direct answer, BUT I recommend using Vue.js for JS heavy tasks (like this one).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, solved this issue using vue.js